# Modifying Dashboard edit.php

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard

[image: dashboard edit.php for custom-post-type]

So I just made a Custom Post Type which doesn't need titles for it's entries.

How can I modify the posts-list in dashboard (see image) so that it would display the post's excerpt/content instead of the usual title?

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the columns for your CPT like so:

```
function edit_cpt_columns($columns){
    $columns = array(
        'cb'        =>  '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title'     =>  __('Post')
    );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-CPT_columns', 'edit_cpt_columns');

function manage_cpt_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $post;

    switch( $column ) {
        case 'title' :
            $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
            echo '<a href="'.$link'">'.$post->post_excerpt.'</a>';
                break;
        default :
                break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_CPT_posts_custom_column', 'manage_cpt_columns', 10, 2);
```

You would need to replace `CPT` with the name of your custom post type.

The first function declares you columns while the 2nd function fills the columns with data.